# SQL: ERROR 1054 (42S22) Unknown column in having clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I have searched through stackoverflow for about an hour without finding a solution for my problem.

```
select   Schueler.Vorname, Schueler.Nachname
from     Schueler, SchuelerLernt, Lehrer, Instrumente
group by Schueler.Snummer
having   Schueler.Snummer = SchuelerLernt.Snummer and
         SchuelerLernt.Lnummer = Lehrer.Lnummer and
         SchuelerLernt.Ibezeichnung = Instrumente.Ibezeichnung and
         count(Ibezeichnung) > 1;
```

when I use the command source test.sql, I get this error message back:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22) Unknown column 'Schueler.Snummer' in 'having
>   clause'

The column exists and I do not know what is wrong.

Is anyone able to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
select Schueler.Snummer, Schueler.Vorname, Schueler.Nachname
from Schueler
JOIN SchuelerLernt
  ON Schueler.Snummer = SchuelerLernt.Snummer
JOIN Lehrer
  ON SchuelerLernt.Lnummer = Lehrer.Lnummer
JOIN Instrumente
  ON SchuelerLernt.Ibezeichnung = Instrumente.Ibezeichnung
group by Schueler.Snummer, Schueler.Vorname, Schueler.Nachname
having count(Ibezeichnung) > 1;
```

You should use `JOIN` syntax instead of comma syntax.

Your `GROUP BY` clause should match `SELECT` clause or use aggregation functions.

**EDIT:**

I don't know any reason why not to use `JOIN` but if you need use:

```
select   Schueler.Snummer, Schueler.Vorname, Schueler.Nachname
from     Schueler, SchuelerLernt, Lehrer, Instrumente
WHERE    Schueler.Snummer = SchuelerLernt.Snummer
  AND    SchuelerLernt.Lnummer = Lehrer.Lnummer
  AND    SchuelerLernt.Ibezeichnung = Instrumente.Ibezeichnung
group by Schueler.Snummer, Schueler.Vorname, Schueler.Nachname
having   count(Ibezeichnung) > 1;
```

Comment: but we have msql at school and we are not allowed to use join. Is there another solution?

Comment: @ednhzrd Added alternative solution. Please tell your teacher than comma syntax is obsolete and should be avoided

Comment: Okay thank you, could you explain why my version is not working?

Comment: @ednhzrd HAVING is for post aggregation filtering, WHERE is for pre aggregation filtering. So you cannot mix them as you want. First join tables, then do aggregation, then filter the result of aggregation